# devc++ compilation errors for 1st time user

Tags: c++, windows-7, compilation, dev-c++

I have this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a,b,c;
    double x,x2;
    cout<<"Give a: ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Give b: ";
    cin>>b;
    cout <<"Give c: ";
    cin>>c;
    if (a==0)
    {
        if (b==0)
        {
            if (c==0)
            {
            cout<<"Solution indeterminable";
            return 0;
            }
            else 
            {
            cout<<"No solution";
            return 0;
            }   
        }
        else
        {
        x=-c/b;
        cout<<"The only root is x: "<<x;
        return 0;
        }

    }
    else
    {
    double b_sqr=b*b;
    if (b_sqr>4*b*c)
        {
        cout<<"Complex roots: ";
        return 0;
        }
    else if (b_sqr==4*b*c)
        {
        x=-b/(2*a);
        cout<<"The only solution is x: "<<x;
        return 0;
        }
    else
        {
            x=-b+(sqrt((b*b)-(4*a*c)))/(2*2);
            x2=-b-(sqrt((b*b)-(4*a*c)))/(2*2);
            cout<<"The first root is x1: "<<x;
            cout<<"The first root is x2: "<<x2;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

When i tried to compile with devc++ these are the errors i got:

```
found dwarf version '4', this reader only handles version 2 information. 
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `__dyn_tls_init_callback' 
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `__cpu_features_init' 
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms' 
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `__mingw_glob' 
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `__mingw_glob' 
  ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is the first time i am using devc++. The code seems ok. any ideas?
The platform i am using is Windows 7 64 bit version.

Comment: Please do not use Dev-C++. It is considered obsolete. Furthermore, it is not a compiler - the underlying compiler for this IDE seems to be MinGW, equivalent to GCC.

Comment: If you want to use an IDE to learn C++, grab Visual studio express for desktop. It's free and easy to set up. If you don't mind digging into command line stuff, use any editor of your preference and mingw. (Or, better yet, either install Linux or use it in a VM.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many many errors and the reccomendation of fellow user More Axes, i moved away from DevC++.

I suggest anyone wanting to use it do the same and stay away from it because it is obsolete.

If you want to use an IDE under the Windows platform, you could use Visual Studio, or Eclipse.

If you just want to use a compiler, just use MinGW. (then don't forget to add the location of the binaries to the PATH environment vairbale, in order to run in from the command line)

Answer (score 1):

i think you receive this error because of your compiler path is not set correct.

this may help you:

`Tools` > `Compiler Options...` and add the compiler folder.